How do I load a local whatsapp backup on my desktop, without interfering with Whatsapp?
How do I load a local whatsapp backup on my desktop, without interfering with Whatsapp? (So  e.g. perhaps via a third party program)
I made a copy of whatsapp following instructions on this android stackexchange question here

Now i'm wondering how I should go about opening it?
One thing that might be an issue, is I took the SIM card out of the smartphone that has whatsapp on it, and put it into a faster smartphone, and that faster smartphone then got stolen(with the SIM card). I'm hoping I don't need access to that SIM card, in order to access the backup.  I at least want to be able to access it via a third party program. So I can see my data without having to rely on Whatsapp to do it, and without interfering with Whatsapp.
